# apt-get update using wrong repo address

Tags: linux, networking, debian, apt

I've inherited a node that used to connect to our internal server to update and download packages. I've since taken out the node from the internal VLAN, deleted the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory, and updated the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to look like the following:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security oldstable/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security oldstable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

When I do `apt-get update`, this is what I see:

```
Err http://deb.debian.org oldstable InRelease                                 

Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease                          

Err http://deb.debian.org oldstable-updates InRelease                         

Err http://deb.debian.org oldstable/updates InRelease

Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to [our internal server]:
Err http://deb.debian.org oldstable Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to [our internal server]:
Err http://deb.debian.org oldstable-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to [our internal server]:
Err http://deb.debian.org oldstable/updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to [our internal server]:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/oldstable/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/oldstable-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/oldstable/updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/oldstable/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to [our internal server]:

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to [our internal server]:

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/oldstable-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to [our internal server]:

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/oldstable/updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to [our internal server]:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm not sure why it's still trying to connect to our internal server that's part of a different VLAN. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I did `apt-config dump` and saw that it has proxy settings. Went into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` and commented out all lines that start with `Acquire::HTTP::Proxy`.